# Ansible jinja looping for elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to generate configuration file for Elasticsearch using Jinja template.

i am facing below challenge.

Let me explain with an example

I have total 3 VMs. Node1; Node2; Node3 (hostnames of VMs)

In Node1 config file. i should have Node2 and Node3 hostname entries
In Node2 config file. i should have Node1 and Node3 hostname entries
in Node3 config file. i should have Node2 and Node1 host entries

For example: 
elasticsearch.yml on node 1 should have below entries

discovery.seed_hosts:
  - node2
  - node3

Elasticsearch.yml on node 2 should have below entries

discovery.seed_hosts:
  - node1
  - node3

Elasticsearch.yml on node 3 should have below entries

discovery.seed_hosts:
  - node2
  - node1

Could you please help to write config file using Jinja template

Thank you 
Amar

Comment: Please improve your question. It is so confusing. Make it more meaningful and understandable.

Comment: I have updated the information. Hope this time, it is clear. Please revert back to me if not.

Comment: Please format your question correctly. Add the code in code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following `hosts.ini` inventory:

```
[elastic]
node1
node2
node3
```

You can get the full list of the machines in the group from any node with:

```
groups['elastic']
```

e.g

```
$ ansible -i hosts.ini node1 -m debug -a msg="{{ groups['elastic'] }}"
node1 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": [
        "node1",
        "node2",
        "node3"
    ]
}
```

If you target a play against that group, you can easily remove the current node from the list using the [`difference` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters):

```
groups['elastic'] | difference([inventory_hostname])
```

e.g.

```
$ ansible -i hosts.ini all -m debug -a msg="{{ groups['elastic'] | difference([inventory_hostname]) }}"
node1 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": [
        "node2",
        "node3"
    ]
}
node2 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": [
        "node1",
        "node3"
    ]
}
node3 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": [
        "node1",
        "node2"
    ]
}
```